# How to prove `(fun _ : nat => False) = Empty_set nat` in Coq?

Tags: coq

How can I prove the following goal in Coq?

```
Require Import Coq.Sets.Ensembles.

Goal (fun _ : nat => False) = Empty_set nat.
```

**Update**. I've tried

```
Proof.
   apply functional_extensionality. intro n.
```

now I have the following subgoal:

```
1 subgoal
n : nat
______________________________________(1/1)
False = Empty_set nat n
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This goal cannot be proved. It can be admitted though (it does not introduce an inconsistency on its own), and it is a consequence of univalence.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Nevertheless, technically speaking, this **can** be proved using `Require Import Coq.Logic.PropExtensionality` which adds an axiom of propositional extensionality, which, in turn, is a special case of the univalence axiom.

Comment: Is _adding an axiom_ really "technically speaking" a proof? I'm not sure...

Comment: Any proof relies on axioms. If you add an axiom, it is a proof, but in a different proof system. Hopefully, a consistent one! :-)